# Print columns in for loop in awk wrt variable value

Tags: shell, loops, unix, for-loop, awk

I am trying to count number of occurrences of a word "is" using `awk` through sample program below:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { count = 0; word="is"; out=$ }
    /word/ {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        if ($(i) == word) count++;
            } 
        }
    END {print "Found word " word count " no of times"}
' data.txt
```

But here the problem is `$(i)` is not being interpreted as column number.
Can you please suggest what should be written in place of `$(i)` to reference the column number (dynamic) as per value of `i` in that line?

Comment: I don't think `$(i)` is the problem, but the `out=$` on line 2.

Comment: Did you try adding a `print $(i)` in the loop to verify your assertion that `$(i)` is not being interpreted as column number? You don't need the parens btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is the field or column number (1, 2, 3, ...) and `$i` is the value in that field:

```
$ echo This is it|awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i" "$i}'
1 This
2 is
3 it
```

So your program:

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN { 
    count = 0
    word="is"
} 
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        if ($(i) == word) 
            count++
} 
END {
    print "Found word " word" "count " no of times"
} 
$ echo This is it|awk -f test.awk
Found word is 1 no of times
```